# Diagnosing the slow performance of my NAS?

Tags: networking, network-attached-storage, bottleneck

I recently built a NAS box on top of ubuntu server.  I have an average transfer of about 10mb/sec over gigabit wire to my computer.  I was hoping you guys could give recommendations on how to pinpoint where the bottleneck is in this system.  To my knowledge the router is only rated at 100mb/sec, and so are the nics (both server, and client), but shouldn't my files be transferring faster then 10mb/sec?  I made sure to shutdown all other traffic when getting the 10mb/sec baseline.

Thanks,
Max.

Comment: When I experience crazy connectivity issues, I usually check duplex settings on devices before anything else.

Comment: What is your disk configuration? one drive will behave much different than a raid5 or raid10 array.

Comment: When they are both set to half duplex 100mbs, they run at 10 mbs, but when set at full duplex, they run at like 30kbs.

Comment: @Brian, right now just drives, I plan on putting a zraid on (with 3 terabyte drives), but held off until I could diagnose the speed issue (don't want to make it worse, if it is the drives).

Comment: Just a quick update, I tried a second router, and a second (wired) computer, they all got the same speed (10 mb/sec) or close.  I tried just a quick copy between drives, and it was transferring at around 100mb/sec, so it isn't hard drives.  Any other thoughts, or am I just doomed to this speed

Comment: 100mb/sec between drives, or 100MB/sec?  If the former, your drives are horribly slow.  Remember that drive transfers are typically measured in MegaBytes, while network transfers are measured in Megabits.

Comment: Note that transferring a 100MB file over a 100mb network should take about 15-20 seconds (since it will transfer at about 8MB/sec ... 100mb speeds are rarely maintained).  Just want to make sure you did not mix up your bits and bytes =)

Comment: yes, I am sorry, 100MB/sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was this for transferring a single file?  Also, is this performance consistent across multiple client machines?  For testing, your best test is to take a very large file (500MB or so) and transfer it.

Here is how I would test it:

- Borrow a laptop for testing, should be different O/S from your current machine(s) if possible
- Send a large file from borrowed laptop to your current test machine (and vice versa)
- Send a large file from borrowed laptop to NAS (and vice versa)
- Send a large file from current test machine to NAS (and vice versa)

If all of the above yield 10Mb speeds, the issue is your router.  If the performance is only slow when transferring to/from the NAS, then the issue is your Ubuntu setup (I'd guess network config, bad driver, etc).  If the issue is only from your current test machine, but the borrowed one works fine, then it's likely a driver issue or config (e.g. duplex setting).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, one thing I could think of is maybe an issue with right performance on the drives, but I will try that, thanks

Comment: Seems like that did it, switching the routers helped a lot